# i am not getting the prices of subscription in androd 12

Tags: android, kotlin, payment, billing, in-app-purchase-receipt

In App Purchase my subscription prices is not showing. it shows only lifetime in App prices in android 12 and other versions showing all prices. where is the mistake? in Android kotlin.

my code

```
 binding.tvPerMonth.text =
    productDetailsList[0].subscriptionOfferDetails?.get(0)?.pricingPhases?.pricingPhaseList?.get(
        1
    )?.formattedPrice
```

and i am using billing version 5.00

.0
this bug is occur only in android 12. why it is and how to release it?